# Проблема с подключением Bootstrap через composer

Tags: bootstrap, composer

В **composer.json** пишу

```
"require": {
              "twig/twig": "~1.0",
              "twbs/bootstrap": "~3.0"
           }
```

и обновляю composer через командную строку, появляются две папки twbs и twig.

Потом в **index.php** пишу require `vendor/autoload.php` и с помощью `echo` вывожу текст, но стиль шрифта не меняется. Самое интересное что twig работает, а bootstrap нет!

Где может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Надо скопировать файлы ассетов (css и js), потому что они должны лежать в папке `public`, а Composer грузит их в папку `vendor`, которая невидима (во всяком случае, должна быть невидима) для внешнего мира.

Примерно так:

```
cp vendor/twitter/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/html5shiv.js public/js/html5shiv.js
cp vendor/twitter/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js public/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Чтобы это происходило автоматически, надо создать скрипт Composer, примерно такого вида:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "post-update-cmd": "MyVendor\\MyClass::postUpdate",
    }
}
```

Подробнее https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md

Другой вариант, гораздо проще - использовать Bootstrap CDN:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```